# On AWS how to guarantee enough Bandwidth between a load agent in service account and target host located in another account of same organization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, networking, performance-testing, amazon-vpc

I need to run a performance test on AWS.
Amazon requires that the load agents ae located in a different account from target server to be tested.

When under same account, I was able to have target bandwidth by using ena, Placement Groups, enhanced network provided by large instances.(but it is not possible for a performance test).

But when I switched to another account for load agent, I get less than 5 Gbits/s probably related to number of hops done to reach target server.

So what are the solutions for this ?

- VPC peering ?
- Shared VPC ?
- Something else ?

Thank you

Comment: How are you load testing? If you're going publically then the internet gateway is capped at 5GBits. Can the traffic be private for your test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of factors will determine the maximum network speed.

[To ensure that resources are distributed across the Availability Zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ram/latest/userguide/working-with-az-ids.html) for a Region, AWS independently map Availability Zones to names for each account. Meaning  an Availability Zone A in one account is not necessarily Availability Zone A in another account. AZs are connected via single [digit millisecond](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-subnet-basics) latency but it will still effect speed.

As you mentioned you cannot create [placement groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html) across accounts and subnets. You can share subnets using [Resource Access Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ram/latest/userguide/what-is.html).

Also as you mentioned, an [instance type](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) will determine the maximum networking speed available to an instance. There are instance types with advanced networking. New instances have speeds greater or equal to 10Gbps.

The network connections have limits too.

With Transit Gateway, Maximum bandwidth (burst) per Availability Zone per VPC connection is 50 Gbps. VPC peering has no aggregate bandwidth.Individual instance network performance limits and flow limits (10 Gbps within a placement group and 5 Gbps otherwise) apply to both options. Only VPC peering supports placement groups. See Building Scalable Secure VPC [whitepaper](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/building-a-scalable-and-secure-multi-vpc-aws-network-infrastructure.pdf)

There is an additional hop with transit gateway and thus additional latency.

If you are connecting VPCs together with a VPN then the [limit is 1.25Gbps](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/faqs/).

If you are going over NAT then the [limit is also 5Gbps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) but can scale to 45Gbps.

In short the theoretically maximum speed over a VPC is 5Gbps without overhead. However there are instances that can handle up to 100Gbps. To achieve the most of the available network bandwidth, you need to be using the latest Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) drivers and you need to make use of multiple traffic flows. As mentioned flows within a Placement Group can reach 10 Gbps; the rest can reach 5 Gbps. When using multiple flows on the high-end instances, you can transfer 100 Gbps between EC2 instances in the same region (within or across AZs), S3 buckets, and AWS services such as Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS), Amazon ElastiCache, and Amazon EMR. For more info see this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-c5n-instances-with-100-gbps-networking/).

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "VPC peering has no aggregate bandwidth" ? Would this be enough or would it be better to use Transit Gateway ? The latter seems to me more here to simplify by centralising rather than guarantee bandwidth. Thanks

Comment: I made some tests here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62364454/performance-test-in-aws-how-to-guarantee-bandwidth

Comment: @JoeMoor there is no bandwidth limit when peered via VPC Peering. See page 7 of this document https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/building-a-scalable-and-secure-multi-vpc-aws-network-infrastructure.pdf